# Azure servicebus with java springboot

Tags: spring-boot, azureservicebus, java-17, azure-servicebus-topics, wildfly-27

I am trying to execute `springboot` application in `wildfly 27` to connect and listen to JMS messages from azure service bus.

Same code is working fine when started with embedded tomcat. But if I exclude tomcat and deploy same war file in `wildfly` it doesn't work.

> **Error** Cause: Cannot create durable subscription - client ID has not been set

How do I get it working in WildFly?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class JiraServiceBusApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JiraServiceBusApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(JiraServiceBusApplication.class);
    }
    
}

@JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
        subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, concurrency = "1")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {


spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string=Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+ASbJ7sBvY=
spring.jms.servicebus.topic-client-id=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
spring.jms.servicebus.pricing-tier=standard
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot with an embedded Tomcat server, the connection is managed by the embedded server itself.

- When deploying to WildFly, the connection is managed by the application server, and you may need to configure the JMS connection factory and client ID accordingly.

JMS Configuration to **WildFly:**

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:10.0">
    <server name="default">
        <jms-connection-factories>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="true" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <!-- Add your custom connection factory configuration here -->
        </jms-connection-factories>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

- Inside the messaging subsystem, find the `<jms-queue>` or `<jms-topic>` configuration for your JMS destination.

```xml
<jms-topic name="yourTopic">
    <entry name="java:/jms/yourTopic"/>
    <durable>true</durable>
</jms-topic>
```

- Open `standalone.xml` file in the WildFly configuration directory, Locate the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">` section in the configuration.

[image]

[image: w]

*Reference:*

- [JMS in Spring to access Azure Service Bus - Java on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus?tabs=use-a-service-bus-queue%2Cpasswordless)
- [JMS queues and topics](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Messaging%20configuration.html#:%7E:text=standalone%2Dfull.xml)

Comment: I am checking similar but why Active MQ is in use here; When we are using Service Bus? Is it possible to handle connection factory on application level in place of servers? May be by adding more dependencies to POM?

Comment: @Suresh. I am bit confused with above settings. If possible please share this setup for wildfly. Or if we can use JMS 2.0 and achieve same using java code?